# Android SQLite: Read dataset in onItemClick

Tags: android, sqlite, onitemclick

The entries in my database are shown via ListView. By clicking an entry I want to save the entry in a file. I know that Cursor holds the related dataset to `long id`,  but I didn't find a method that lets me obtain it.

Thanks in advance for your time :)

```
...
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);     

    String[] columns = new String[] { "s1", "s2",
            "s3", "s4", "s5", "s6" };

    int[] datasetViews = new int[] { R.id.col1, R.id.col2, R.id.col3,
            R.id.col4, R.id.col5, R.id.col6 };


    simpleCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.dataset, cursor, columns, datasetViews,
            CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);

    listView.setAdapter(simpleCursorAdapter);
    listView.setClickable(true);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
            /* simpleCursorAdapter.getItem(position) gives me
                    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@447c8888, but I want the    
            content of the cursor. How do I do that? */
        }
    });
}
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First thing you need to do is create a model class for your data with getters and accessors.
2. Then create a custom adapter, although not necessary.
3. Return list with items from your DB.
4. Add that list to the array adapter.
5. Use the position for getting an item..
6. use your getters from the object model to get the data you want.

   //try this

   enter code here

   String itemName = ((YourModel) getListAdapter().getItem(position)).getYourItemName();

Then you can save the item value.

Comment: I already implemented all those classes (I thought it's a bit too much to post them here, but if you it's necessary, I'll post them). It's just about what I have to do in the onItemClick method.

Comment: The "missing link" was `Cursor c = simpleCursorAdapter.getCursor(); c.moveToPosition(position);`. Thanks for answering, Chloe33 :)